# RowDataBound prevent RowUpdating event being fired

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, gridview

Currently I am using an unbound GridView and it has RowUpdating event to edit/update data to db. I was also using RowDataBound event to group sub Headers for all columns. 
However I noticed that ever since RowDatabound is added, the RowUpdating event doesn't get fired at all. The moment RowDataBound is removed, the programme works as usual.

I need to group Sub Headers with one main Header. What could be the reason behind this issue?
What are the solutions I can fix and get it going as per requirements.

EDIT : Code per request in comments;

```
     ///<summary>
     ///Adding sub headers to gridview
     ///</summary>
     ///<param name="sender"></param>
     ///<param name="e"></param>
    protected void GridView2_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        //columns
        GridViewRow outerGridView = e.Row;            

        if (outerGridView.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
        {
            GridViewRow gvrow = new GridViewRow(0, 0, DataControlRowType.Header, DataControlRowState.Insert);

            TableCell cell0 = new TableCell();
            cell0.Text = "Project Details";
            cell0.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Center;
            cell0.ColumnSpan = 6;

            TableCell cell1 = new TableCell();
            cell1.Text = "Monday";
            cell1.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Center;
            cell1.ColumnSpan = 2;

            TableCell cell2 = new TableCell();
            cell2.Text = "Tuesday";
            cell2.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Center;
            cell2.ColumnSpan = 2;

            TableCell cell3 = new TableCell();
            cell3.Text = "Wednesday";
            cell3.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Center;
            cell3.ColumnSpan = 2;

            GridView2.Controls[0].Controls.AddAt(0, gvrow);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you post your aspx and codebehind for the gridview and event?

Comment: @KiranHegde In the mean time I have used `OnRowCreated` event. But yeah, above is the code and take a look at it please.

Comment: There is no reason why it should stop the event being fired. Most likely you did not register or wireup the event handlers

Comment: Good point @Ahmedilyas but I wonder how I could *generate* this event in the first place - if I hadn't clicked on the gridview control, then its properties and `events` tab followed by the `RowDataBound` ;) ? So wiring-up isn't the issue in my case.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow.... ?

Comment: `protected void GridView2_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)` : that isn't hand type code... You know how it's generated, only when controls are wired up!

Comment: There must be something wrong in your HTML code, Try to produce the same in a new entirely Web Page...

Comment: Yeah I guess I should do that. But for now rushing for a prototype...for demo.